# Project cannot be build after update angular 11 to 12. ｢wdm｣: TypeError: Cannot read property 'colors' of undefined

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm apologize if it isn't the place to ask it and for my english.

I'm trying to update the angular version from 11 to 12 but it caused a problem.
I'm using @angular-builders/custom-webpack but I thing it caused error in v12, so I installed webpack@5, is it the possible problem?

When I run 'ng s', the message bellow is returned:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQeak.png)

I already removed package-lock.json and node_modules and installed the packages again but it doesn't work.

This is my package.json, the problem maybe are in it?

```
{
  "name": "my-webpack-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --hmr",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "tsc --noEmit && eslint . --ext js,ts,json --quiet --fix",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode=development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "serve": "webpack serve"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "12.0.0-beta.35",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.17",
    "@iconify/icons-emojione": "^1.0.7",
    "@iconify/icons-fa-brands": "^1.0.12",
    "@iconify/icons-fa-solid": "^1.0.10",
    "@iconify/icons-ic": "^1.0.11",
    "@iconify/icons-logos": "^1.0.11",
    "@iconify/icons-mdi": "^1.0.11",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "~5.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "~5.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.29",
    "@visurel/iconify-angular": "^11.0.0",
    "@zxing/browser": "^0.1.4",
    "@zxing/library": "^0.20.0",
    "@zxing/ngx-scanner": "^2.0.1",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.16",
    "angularx-qrcode": "~2.3.4",
    "apexcharts": "^3.19.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.14.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.3",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "highlight.js": "^10.0.0",
    "html-to-image": "^1.9.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "jspdf": "^2.1.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "luxon": "^1.23.0",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-barcode": "0.3.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^11.1.5",
    "ngx-quill": "^13.4.0",
    "ngx-showdown": "~6.0.0",
    "ngx-signaturepad2": "^1.0.2",
    "ngx-take-until-destroy": "^5.4.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.2",
    "print-js": "^1.6.0",
    "quill": "~1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "showdown": "^1.9.1",
    "simplebar": "~5.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1",
    "uuid": "^8.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.0.0",
    "@fullhuman/purgecss-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/highlight.js": "^9.12.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/luxon": "~1.22.0",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.2",
    "@types/showdown": "~1.9.3",
    "@types/simplebar": "~5.1.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.9.0",
    "@webpack-cli/generators": "^3.0.7",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.74",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.9.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^5.0.1",
    "karma": "^6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.33",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "postcss-scss": "~2.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "prettier-eslint": "^11.0.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.70.0",
    "sass-loader": "^14.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.4",
    "tailwindcss-dir": "~4.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0"
  }
}
```

It is the result when I run ng version :

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.18
```

```
Node: 14.21.3
```

```
Package Manager: npm 6.14.18
```

```
OS: darwin x64
```

```
Angular: 12.2.17
```

```
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
```

```
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
```

```
... router
```

```
Package                            Version
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1202.18
```

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular      12.2.18
```

```
@angular-devkit/core               12.2.18
```

```
@angular-devkit/schematics         12.2.18
```

```
@angular/cdk                       12.2.13
```

```
@angular/cli                       12.2.18
```

```
@angular/flex-layout               12.0.0-beta.35
```

```
@angular/material                  12.2.13
```

```
@angular/material-moment-adapter   12.2.13
```

```
@schematics/angular                12.2.18
```

```
rxjs                               6.6.7
```

```
typescript                         4.9.5
```

```
webpack                            5.90.0
```

I already tried change ts versions, devkit but nothing worked...

Comment: I would consider copying the error message and putting into your message rather then using an image.